# Hibernate encoding: character "trademark" saved correctly but not loaded in jsf page

Tags: hibernate, encoding

I have a jsf page with input text fields. When I type string with special character like ™ the string is saved properly into my DB (using Hibernate) but when I want to load again it results without the character ™. 
I try to put in my hibernate cfg :

```
    <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>
```

but I have the same result.

Comment: How is this jsf related? I only see hibernate config properties... And who gave you the upvoted?

Comment: JSF implicitly uses `UTF-8`. How do you verify that cycle? And on the database side, better pass appropriate parameters via a connection URL and leave it to the target JDBC driver.

Comment: @Tiny: Why using the connection string to pass parameters instead of via properties? Care to elaborate or post a link to a reference why?

Comment: @Kukeltje I specified jsf because the string input is via a field in a jsf page. I don't know who gave me the upvoted and I don't care, I just want to solve my problem

Comment: Tags are not for what is 'used' but for what is identifiable part of the problem. Itentifiable in the way that there is an [mcve] that demonstrates the problem

Comment: @Kukeltje : A matter of choice. Those are Hibernate specific properties. I tend to avoid proprietary features as many as possible no matter how powerful they are as I emphasize portability.

Comment: @Tiny: Ah, in that way, yes I agree then...